# Output additional details to command line using tasklist

Tags: windows, cmd, task, taskmanager, tasklist

So I am trying to do something I thought would be simple little script.

All I want is to output to file (CSV or whatever) output from TaskMgr in Windows.

If I use `tasklist /v /fo csv > data.csv` I get most but not all columns I want.
I want to be able to get the extra columns that are available in details as well.

[image]

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What about this: `wmic Process list`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.
If anyone else wonders just use pslist.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pslist